# Finding probability distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A fair die is rolled independently 3 times.
Define 
$X_i =$ 1 if the i-th roll yields a perfect square $0$ otherwise.
Suppose $Y$ = $X_1 + X_2 + X_3$.
Find the p.m.f.of Y and its d.f.

I found P($X_i$=1) = $19/27$ and P($X_i$=0)=$8/27$ , P(Y) = $0$ when y=0 P(Y) = when $0$<=Y<1 answer is not coming correct.

Comment: Please update the question to include your attempt.

Comment: Can you put a bit more information about why you think that $P(x_i = 1) = 19/27$. How many different ways to role a single dice are there? And how many rolls return a perfect square?

Comment: @owen88 i believe getting a perfect square is getting a perfect square on any of the three roll and thats how i got P($X_i$=1) = $19/27$ and P($X_i$=0)=$8/27$

Comment: You define X_i = 1 if the $i$-th roll is a perfect square, so this depends on only one of the rolls.

Comment: Even then, you have still not explained why 19/27; where does this come from?

Comment: @owen88 only outcomes that are perfect square are 1,4 so the probability of getting a perfect square on a single dice roll = $2/6$ = $1/3$ and probability of getting no perfect squares on a single roll = $2/3$. Now because we are rolling 3 times probability = ($2/3$)*($2/3$)*($2/3$) = $8/27$ and probability of its complement = 1- $8/27$ = $19/27$

Comment: Hopefully my answer below is helpful and clarifies the problem for you. I see that you are new to mathstackexchange; can I please ask that if this was helpful you accept (click the tick to the left of my answer) the answer. Stackexchange sites survive by people donating their time to help each other, and accepting is a simple way to give back. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comment you correctly note that the probability that a single roll shows a perfect square (i.e. a $1$ or $4$) is $2/6 = 1/3$. Therefore we have
$$P(X_i = 1) = \frac13.$$

Assuming that each of the rolls is independent, then $Y = 0$ occurs only if all three rolls are $0$, i.e.

$$\mathbf P[Y = 0] = \mathbf P[ X_1 = X_2 = X_3 = 0] = \left( \frac23\right)^3 = \frac8{27}$$

Similarly $Y = 1$ if only one of the three dice show a $1$, i.e.
\begin{align*}
\mathbf P[Y = 1] &= \mathbf P[ X_1 =1, X_2 = X_3 = 0] + \mathbf P[ X_1 =0, X_2 =1,\, X_3 = 0] + \mathbf P[ X_1 = X_2 =0, \, X_3 = 1] \\
& = 3  \left(\frac13\right) \left(\frac23\right)^2 \\
& = \frac49
\end{align*}

Hopefully this now gives you a hint how to calculate the probabilities of $Y = 2$ and $Y= 3$.

If you are already familiar with the Binomial distribution then this is simply saying that $Y \sim \text{Bin}(3,p)$ with $p = \frac13$ the probability that a single roll is a perfect square.

Comment: $F_Y(0)=1/3$ and at 1  is 5/9

Comment: According to who?

Comment: the answers provided

Comment: it seems that answer is wrong, Thanks for your response.

Comment: No problem; I'm confident that the answer provided (i.e. your comment above) is incorrect, and that the derivation above is accurate.